# Local HTML with Hyperlink in JEditorPane to be Intercepted by Method

Tags: java, swing, methods, hyperlink, jeditorpane

Does anyone know of a way to take a local HTML file and fire a Java method on clicking a hyperlink?
 The HTML is a bunch of tables with a link on each row.
The HTML is to be displayed in a tab within a pure Java program (no JavaFX).
 Is there a simple way to parse the raw HTML to handle the hyperlink?

This is my starting point for testing.
[Display html contents with java](http://mrbool.com/display-html-contents-with-java/24532)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`addHyperlinkListener(HyperlinkListener)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html#addHyperlinkListener(javax.swing.event.HyperlinkListener)) method to capture events related to the user clicking the link. Note that the editor pane needs to be non-editable before events are fired.